# Mapping a 2d image to a pseudo 3d

Tags: 3d, technique

Hi I am unsure what to call this technique that Live2D uses and I wanted get some more information about it.

Here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XW6Yrxnn5dM

You can see how they add the 2D textures then they can give it a pseudo 3d effect like turning the head and having the face and stuff move somewhat realistically.

What's this technique called?

Comment: Looks to just be Puppet Warp in Photoshop. (Didn't watch the video, just fast forwarded it)

Comment: I was just searching same but different :"how to take a 2d image and make it into 3d for a 3d printer, i found omnomnom creator and a blender tutorial to do that with a pic and a heightmap omnom is only on mac :/

Answer (score 1):

It is a specific aplication: http://www.live2d.com/en/products/cubism_editor. Too bad it is not in english.

It is a program to make animations, like you can see in the keyframe editor on the bottom.

The principle is a parallax effect. It is somehow common in website design theese days. http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/ In a website you can make it interactive. On that program looks optimised for animation.

It also has some morphing controls.

I am wondering if that can be done in a real3D aplication like blender using inverse kinematics... Yea... I have homework to do...

Updated: Yea its pártially in english and it has a free version.